# Pythonic way to associate list of dataframes to list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, list, depth-first-search

In encountered this problem when converting a json object to a csv:

I now have two lists:

list_A is a list of strings. Each string is a name of df.

```
list_A = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']
```

list_B has 3 pandas.core.frame.DataFrame objects.

```
list_B[0] = [an entire df with columns, rows etc]
```

What code would ensure association between strings from the one list with the dataframes in the other, such as df1 = list_B[0] then df2 = list_B[1] and so on?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use a dictionary:

`dfs = dict(zip(list_A, list_B))`

then access individual dataframes with `dfs['df1']`:

```
list_a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_b = [1, 2, 3]
d = dict(zip(list_a, list_b))
print(d['a'])
# 1
```

or hack `locals`:

```
for name, df in zip(list_A, list_B):
    locals()[name] = df
```

Then you can access individual dataframes directly, `df1`, `df2` etc:

```
list_a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_b = [1, 2, 3]
for key, value in zip(list_a, list_b):
    locals()[key] = value
print(a)
#  1
```

Comment: You sir, earned a cookie

Comment: Don't hack `locals` though. That is such bad practice.

Answer (score 5):

You can associate them with a `dict`:

```
df_dict = dict(zip(list_A, list_B))

df_dict['df1'].head() ## Returns the first 10 rows of list_B[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want three variables, the best way to do it is to assign them like this:

```
df1, df2, df3 = list_B
```

This will unpack the list giving values to each variable.

For too many variables use:

```
{'df{}'.format(i): df for i, df in enumerate(list_B, 1)}
```

Comment: No, yeah, definitely I can do this, but its just that I want a pythonic way, what if there are like, a million different values instead of just a few?

Comment: @blacksatius Okay, then you'd go with dict and use the example in edit. And unpacking __is__ pythonic.